# NeoVim JavaScript completion with DefinitelyTyped in deoplete

Tags: javascript, typescript, autocomplete, definitelytyped, neovim

I'm using neovim and VSCode to write JavaScript code. I'm using [deoplete](https://github.com/Shougo/deoplete.nvim) as completion engine.

In VSCode, I could use [DefinitelyTyped](http://definitelytyped.org/)'s JavaScript library definition files to complete JavaScript. It seems to be related with tsserver (Microsoft's TypeScript server) somehow.

But in NeoVim, I cannot benefit from the type definition files to complete JavaScript. It seems that deoplete can complete TypeScript with it, but it can't complete JavaScript.

Is there any way to complete JavaScript via DefinitelyTyped type definition files in deoplete?